# Regarding package management tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I think we should symlink [package-manager](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-manager) and [package-management](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-management) tags. They are too similar to be separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added the [package-management](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-management) ← [package-manager](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-manager) synonym ([package-manager](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-manager) is more common, but the synonym going that way doesn't really make sense to me). Will merge later